# How to perform platt scaling for hyperparameter-optimized model?

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter, grid-search

I'm using Python and have a best estimator from a grid search. Wanted to be able to calibrate the probability output accordingly, but would like to know more about implementing platt scaling. From what I've seen, calibration can either be done through a test-set or cross-validation, and consensus seems to be that latter option is better.

When it comes to **CalibratedClassifierCV**, there is an input for **cv** which can be an **int**, but can also have a string **"prefit"** suggesting that the classifier has already been fitted. However, it seems like using **"prefit"** does not end up with cross-validation being performed and using an int for cv would recalibrate the model by going through the grid search twice.

```
CalibratedClassifierCV(grid_CV_clf.best_estimator_, cv =2)
```

I can still fix my grid search with a **KFold** object for the **GridSearchCV: cv** argument to ensure model isn't recalibrated when doing something like above.

So to list the options I have:

- I can fix my model and run crossvalidation for calibrated classifier. However, from example above, it will run GridSearchCV each time, so total number of steps will be **(GridSearchCV:cv * CalibratedClassifierCV: cv)**
- I can use "prefit" and it'll calibrate training data onetime
- I can simply calibrate one time with my test set while holding model as "prefit"

Would appreciate if someone could help me better understand what the right approach is or let me know of another option I may not have thought of.

Thanks